# Querying Oracle 11g multidimensional cube from sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, olap-cube, oracle-olap

Im new to oracle multidimensional models...

I have followed the "Creating a Multidimensional Model" 15 min Oracle tutorial. [Tutorial Link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/datamodel3genmulti/datamodel3genmulti_otn.htm)
Note: This tutorial use sql developer data modeler.

**I would like to know how to query the created data cube using SQL Developer (I.E. using regular SQL DML statements).** Every time I look for information online I end up getting links on how to use the Oracle Analytic Workspace Manager. Why?  I would like to just build the cube and query it without having to make use of the Oracle Analytic Workspace Manager.

I would appreciate if somone could let me know if I am missing some steps. (a short simple example would be nice)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize you asked this in August 2013, but in case it still helps you or others, as of Feb 2014, SQL Developer has an OLAP extension which seems to be what you were looking for...

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-releasenotes-v4-1925251.html

> The OLAP extension enables you to use the familiar environment of SQL
>   Developer to create and manage dimensional objects in Oracle Database
>   12c Release 1 (12.1.0.1.0) or higher. Oracle OLAP provides advanced
>   multidimensional analytic capabilities and storage within the
>   database, including excellent query performance, fast incremental data
>   updates, efficient management of summary data, and rich analytic
>   content, such as time series calculations and both additive and
>   nonadditive aggregations.