# Can you create OLAP cubes using Oracle SQL Developer or Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssms, oracle-sqldeveloper, olap-cube

Can you create OLAP cubes using Oracle SQL Developer or Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft SQL Server:

You can access SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) OLAP cubes from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
In order to create cubes, you'll need to install [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) (SSDT).

> Oracle:

[Analytic Workspace Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28124/cubes.htm#OLAUG300) is the primary tool for creating, developing, and managing dimensional objects in Oracle Database.

There is also an Oracle SQL Developer OLAP extension. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22775054/327165) for details.